# understanding a simple Perl construct

Tags: perl

as a not Perl programmer, i would like to be sure i had well understood a construct that i am going to port to Python,

when using :

```
if (s/^([$PChar])(.)/$2/) {
  print $1,"\n";
  $finished = 0;
}
```

- $1, $2 etc. are matching regular expression
- s/search for/replace with/

what i am really not sure is does the matching/replacement is done before the print $1 ? and is it done "inplace" inside current buffer (which is $F, that is $_ line by line readed, splitted on its space character), that is changing it (so if i understand well, the ([$PChar]) when @ beginning of a string is totally striped off/lost in the above statment) ?

EDIT : no maybe it is not lost, first parenthesis part is captured, and then printed as $1 + new line character and then... no, do not understand what become $2... may be buffer change to second parenthesis part ? /END OF EDIT.

also is there any environnement or what is the best environnement that permit to do some step-by-step debugging on Win platform ? i'm aware that having this, i will not have asked this question. And i do not need to learn Perl, just only to be able to read and adapt this script.

here is the englobing part :

```
@F = split;
for( $j=0; $j<=$#F; $j++) {
  my $suffix="";
  $_ = $F[$j];
  # separate punctuation and parentheses from words
  do {
$finished = 1;
# cut off preceding punctuation
if (s/^([$PChar])(.)/$2/) {
  print $1,"\n";
  $finished = 0;
}
# cut off trailing punctuation
if (s/(.)([$FChar])$/$1/) {
  $suffix = "$2\n$suffix";
  $finished = 0;
}
```

whole script tokenize.pl can be seen [here](http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/tools/public/uplug/ext/tree-tagger/cmd/tokenize.pl) while original tar.bz if from [here](ftp://ftp.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/pub/corpora/tagger-scripts.tar.gz)

best regards

Comment: If you're going to post sample code, don't post a tar.gz file, copy and paste the plain text to some online codepad, like codepad.org.

Comment: @TLP, ok thank you ! i did not know codepart.org until now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# try to delete the first character from the string contained in
# $_ if that character is one of the characters contained in
# the string $PChar. The deletion is done by replace the first and
# second character by only the second character.
if (s/^([$PChar])(.)/$2/) {

  # if the replacement was successful, print the deleted character.
  print $1,"\n";
  $finished = 0;
}
```

Comment: The comments from the question suggest that $PChar holds a string of punctuation marks. I didn't look at the tar, but let's assume `$PChar = '\.,:;]'`. Then `([$PChar])` would capture exactly one of the characters `.`, `,`, `:`, `;`. An easier way to achieve the same would be to just leave the second parenthesis and say `s/^([$PChar])//` because it doesn't touch the next char anyway.

Comment: and then the rest of the processus continue with only the string starting with the second character as being our new buffer $_ ? or do we continue with all the string unchanged as $_ ?

Simbabque : yes it is actually punctuation opening marks like opening bracket.

Comment: @user1340802: The replacements are inline which means the contents of `$_` get changed (first character dropped).

Comment: [This](http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/tools/public/uplug/ext/tree-tagger/cmd/tokenize.pl) might be the script he is looking at

Comment: @TLP, yes it is :) thank you. Sorry do not have found this one as it is a mirror from the orginal website i pointed.